# First sci-fi based explicitly on the Hiroshima bomb?

Tags: history-of, nuclear-weapons

Reading the synopsis of *Frankenstein Conquers the World* (1965), it involves a feral child who was affected by the bombing of Hiroshima. (It really sounds kind of intriguing despite apparently goofy aspects and production values.)

Although earlier movies had "atomic" monsters, I wonder if this was the first (and maybe only) science fiction/horror flick that explicitly involved the Hiroshima (or Nagasaki) bombing?

EDIT: Earliest stories is different than first movies but interesting nonetheless.

Comment: It's definitely not the *only* sci-fi movie to involve the Hiroshima bombing - *The Wolverine* depicts it at the beginning - but I too would be interested to know whether it was the first.

Comment: yes, of course -- i forgot about Wolverine. but first seems possible since i would guess Hiroshima for years was just too painful to trivialize in a film. i am sure for many who were alive then, not even living in either city, the abomb was never far from their thoughts. (and perhaps they never stopped worrying completely that it would happen again).

Comment: "Based explicitly" as in named in the movie, or would a director's commentary suffice. Because Godzilla was created as an allegory for those two atomic bombs and that was explicitly mentioned by its creators. I don't think the cities were named in the movie, though. That would push the year to 1954.

Comment: Related reading - US Cinema just [doesn't do Hiroshima](https://www.theguardian.com/film/2010/aug/15/hollywood-hiroshima-ronald-bergan-films)

Comment: Would you accept a film with the Nagasaki bombing instead?

Comment: @JohnP: interesting. this i guess i observed without knowing for sure. it is to many in USA (i hope) a deep shame.

Comment: @Buzz: I would -- surprising that there would be a nagasaki-related flick before a Hirsoshima one.

Comment: Just pointing out that _[Godzilla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godzilla)_ (1954) is premised on post Hiroshima Pacific nuclear testing.  But clearly Hiroshima was still in the minds of the filmmakers, because Gojira/Godzilla's "skin texture was inspired by the keloid scars seen on survivors in Hiroshima."

Comment: @Spencer and the opening scenes in the US version when describing the effects of the monster are pretty on the nose in terms of the human devestation of atomic weapons

Comment: @Kakturus: No, everyone watching a Japanese-made flick that involved atomic bombs or radiation or simply some huge menace would understand that the atomic bombing of Japan inspired this -- much more interesting is the explicit mention and so far it looks like Frankenstein CTW is the first film to be do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1946:** ["Loophole"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41198), a short story by [Arthur C. Clarke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_C._Clarke), first published in [*Astounding Science Fiction*, April 1946](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?57384+c), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Astounding_v37n02_1946-04_cape1736#page/n56/mode/1up).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loophole_(short_story)) summary:

> The story begins in the form of correspondence between the President of Mars and the Secretary of the Martian Council of Scientists, regarding the discovery of atomic power (in the form of atomic bombs) by humans. They are concerned that once humanity's current war is over (they have been monitoring Earth's broadcasts), humans will use atomic power and rockets to breach interplanetary space and pose a threat to Mars. A remote monitoring station is set up by Mars on the Moon to monitor Earth's progress. Finally they send a fleet of 19 battleships along with a warning to Earth that one city will be destroyed every time a rocket leaves Earth's atmosphere. Earth agrees to stop experimenting with rockets when they realize their broadcasts are being intercepted. Ten years pass without any further rocket experimentation, while the Martians plan for the extermination of the human race, believing that Earth will always be a threat to them.

Excerpt from story:

> From: Secretary, Council of Scientists.
>
> To: President.
>
> The facts are as follows. Some months ago our instruments detected intense neutron emission from Earth, but an analysis of radio programs gave no explanation at
> the time. Three days ago a second emission occurred and soon afterwards all radio transmissions from Earth announced that atomic bombs were in use in the current war. The
> translators have not completed their interpretation, but it appears that the bombs are of considerable power. Two have so far been used. Some details of their construction have been released, but the elements concerned have not yet been identified. A fuller, report will be forwarded as soon as possible. For the moment all that is certain is that the inhabitants of Earth have liberated atomic power, so far only explosively.

Comment: I bet this is the first science fiction story to deal with the attacks on Hiroshima and Nagasaki but still want to know if Franksenstein Conquers the World has the distinction of being the first fiction film about Hiroshima (or Nagasaki).

Answer (score 3):

A very early (1947) example of a story that turns out to have a lot to do with the consequences of an early nuclear explosion (although it was the Trinity test in New Mexico, not one of the bombs dropped on Japan in 1945) is "[The Figure](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?45687)" by Edward Grendon (a pseudonym for the psychologist Lawrence LeShan).

> It didn't make the newspapers, but about a year after the New Mexico atom bomb test, the insect problem at the testing ground suddenly increased a hundredfold.

The whole story is [available online](https://archive.org/stream/Astounding_v39n05_1947-07_AK#page/n45/mode/1up).  It was also the answer to [this story identification question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/201932/short-story-from-70s-or-80s-statue-of-a-cockroach-brought-back-from-the-future).

Answer (score 2):

Possibly Alfred Bester's "Hobson's Choice" 1952

It involves a government agent in a post-WW3 America sent to a place where, inexplicably, the population has risen. He finds that the growth is due to the arrival of time-travellers from the future. He wants to leave his devastated world, but they caution him that he will be even more unhappy in the totally alien future one.

The story ends with a Japanese refugee begging for a visa because he wants so desperately to go home - to Hiroshima!